# RequireJS - not seeing variables from inside the page

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm trying to work out why I keep getting these errors in my new site:

```
<script data-main="/2018/v5/js/app" src="/2018/v5/js/lib/require.js" async="true"></script>
<title>Title</title>

<script>window.VARS = {
 thisPage: "home_new",
 temp_set: "luna"
 };
</script>
```

However, in *some* (and by some, I mean not many at all), I get an error:

> TypeError: window.VARS is undefined

[image]

I think the issue is around the fact `window.VARS` is set in the body (we use this to transfer params related to the page). Would simply moving it around the DOM help? ie:

```
<title>Title</title>

<script>window.VARS = {
 thisPage: "home_new",
 temp_set: "luna"
 };
</script>
<script data-main="/2018/v5/js/app" src="/2018/v5/js/lib/require.js" async="true"></script>
```

Its hard to test, as I've not been able to replicate this issue at all - but I'm seeing the errors in Errorception.com (the system we use for tracking external errors), so I'm aware its an issue. I'd just like to fix it up if entirely possible.

Comment: Yes, that should fix your problem

Comment: @WillJenkins thanks for that. I always assumed the DOM would be loaded *before* the JS was processing. I'll give it a go and see if that sorts it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should fix your problem, but it's good practice in any case to guard against this sort of race condition like this :

```
 window.VARS = window.VARS || {};
 window.VARS.thisPage= "home_new";
 window.VARS.temp_set= "luna"
```

and follow that same pattern every time you attempt to set properties on it.

Another simpler way that I've just realised would be to `defer` your script execution until after the page has loaded:

```
 <script data-main="/2018/v5/js/app" src="/2018/v5/js/lib/require.js" async="true" defer></script>
```

Comment: Thanks. So would `window.VARS = window.VARS || {} ` go in the HTML body, or the javascript files?

Comment: Both, but the syntax needs adjusting as in the (updated) answer so you add properties rather than replace the whole object.

Comment: Thanks. Would the `defer` cause a slowdown in the page?

Comment: it depends on what you're doing, but it won't slow the initial page load. It will ensure that your variable is available though.